# Creating plugin with jQuery that gets element from an external svg file and use the elements height for DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin that can be used to get elements from an external SVG file and get the height of one of the elements in the file for DOM manipulation. I have the SVG in my html as

```html
<object id="third" class="triangles" data="triangles1.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%"></object>
```

and I can set the position of the SVG on my page with jQuery and vanilla JavaScript

```js
$(window).on('load', () => {
  var svgThird = document.querySelectorAll('.triangles')[2]
  var doc = svgThird.contentDocument
  var group = doc.getElementById('first-set')
  var setHeight = group.getBoundingClientRect().height

  svgThird.style.marginTop = `-${setHeight * 2}px`

  $(window).resize(() => {
    var setHeight = group.getBoundingClientRect().height

    svgThird.style.marginTop = `-${setHeight * 2}px`
  })
})
```

But I can't seem to create a plugin to do something similar as it can't seem to read `contentDocument`. I have searched pretty much anywhere I can for a jQuery alternative to `contentDocument` that will still allow me to do what I have done above but with my own plugin and I haven't found anything.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this please? Unless it's not possible to use JavaScript in a jQuery plugin? Thank you.

Comment: What plugin? I don't see any or `contentDocument`.

Comment: @zer00ne Hi, I'm trying to create the jQuery plugin that will have the same function as the code above. My thought is that I'd have to use the contentDocument property in the plugin I'm trying to create as well to retrieve the elements inside the svg file as I am doing above. I'm not sure if there's another way around it as I get the error that jQuery can't read the contentDocument property. Please let me know if I'm not explaining this right

Comment: jQuery method [.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) is `.contentDocument` equivalent

Comment: SVG can't be converted into a jQuery Object AFAIK. Ex. `$('svg')`, but there is [this](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)

Comment: @zer00ne Thanks so much. I'll try that and hopefully it works. Thank you.